# expected ‘struct matrix_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct matrix_t *’ ?_? no difference

Tags: c, pointers, types, struct

```
main.c:78:25: erreur: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
main.c:81:9: erreur: passing argument 2 of ‘matrix_multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
main.c:6:11: note: expected ‘struct matrix_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct matrix_t *’
```

line 6 is the matrix_multiply function

here is my code which begin at line 74

```
matrix_t *m;
matrix_t *first = matrix_reader_next(reader);
matrix_t *previous = first;
while ( (m = matrix_reader_next(reader))) {
    previous->next = m;
    previous = m;
}
matrix_t *result = matrix_multiply(first,first->next);
```

and here are my function prototypes and structure

```
typedef struct {
   int **M;
   int nLi;
   int nCo;
   struct matrix_t *next;
} matrix_t;

matrix_t* matrix_multiply(matrix_t* first, matrix_t*second);
matrix_t* matrix_reader_next(matrix_reader_t *r);
```

I really don't understand these error message. Please help me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type definition should read

```
typedef struct matrix_t {
   int **M;
   int nLi;
   int nCo;
   struct matrix_t *next;
} matrix_t;
```

Otherwise, the type `matrix_t` refers to a complete but unnamed structure type, whereas `struct matrix_t` refers to a different, named but incomplete structure type which you never define.

Comment: That's clear now :) Thank you for your quick answer, there is no warning anymore!

Answer (score 7):

Change your `struct` definition to this:

```
typedef struct matrix_t {
   int **M;
   int nLi;
   int nCo;
   struct matrix_t *next;
} matrix_t;
```

Notice the difference?

`struct matrix_t` is not the same as `typedef ... matrix_t`; they exist in different namespaces; so in your version of the code, the compiler assumes that `struct matrix_t *next` refers to a different, incomplete type.

Answer (score 3):

Aha, you don't have a `struct matrix_t` yet the `next` field is declared using a struct tag. This then causes problems whenever the `next` field is used.

`matrix_t` *could* be both a struct tag and a type name, as they are in different namespaces, but as it is, your definition starts with...

```
struct {
```

not...

```
struct matrix_t {
```

In other words, you have an *unnamed* struct which has a typedef called `matrix_t` but you never actually define a `struct matrix_t.`