# Inclusion related errors. Compiler does not recognize previously declared structures

Tags: c, include

I am getting strange errors from GCC such as

```
main.c:117:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘Adsorbate_Timestep’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
Adsorbate.h:95:6: note: expected ‘struct Substrate *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Substrate *’
```

Notice the expected argument is identical to the actual one.

I have several header files which define their own structures and declare functions which use those structures, and structures from other header files as well.

SOLVED:

Solution was to make sure each header file has at least a deceleration of each struct (of course the struct defined in the header file need not be declared again).

Comment: `expected ‘struct Substrate *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Substrate *’` Really weird!!!

Comment: please show us the code in main.c around line 117 and absorbate.h around line 95...

Comment: Do you have by any chance 2 different definitions of "struct Substrate" in main.c and Adsorbate.h.

Comment: mathematician1975, you sure you want to? It's a code written by a science graduate student. could burn your retina. I will try to make it concise.

Comment: refere to http://sscce.org/ for short self contained code, that will produce the same error...

Comment: binW, no. I checked. All decelerations and definitions are limited to the header files.

Comment: @MickeyDiamant Well then I am eagerly waiting for the code

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846951/expected-struct-matrix-t-but-argument-is-of-type-struct-matrix-t-no. Yours seem exact same situation.

Comment: The code that you added doesnt contain the definition of <b>struct Substrate</b> and neither it contains <b>main.c</b>. So they are not really helpful for the original error you mentioned. Also there is another warning that you have mentioned which should be different question.